# Possible bug in Filament v3 EditTenantProfile?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I have followed the documentation [here](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/tenancy) to setup and configure tenancy in my Filament app.  It's all working fine, except for my Tentant Profile page (as described [here](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/tenancy#adding-a-tenant-profile-page%3E)).  As far as I can tell I have followed the instructions to the letter.

I have the following custom tenant profile file at `app/Filament/Pages/Tenancy/EditOrganizationProfile.php:

```
namespace App\Filament\Pages\Tenancy;

use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Select;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Repeater;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Pages\Tenancy\EditTenantProfile;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Section;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Grid;
class EditOrganizationProfile extends EditTenantProfile
{
   public static function getLabel(): string
    {
        return 'Organization Profile';
    }
    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form->schema([
            TextInput::make('name')
        ]);
    }
}
```

I am using this in my panel provider like:

```
use App\Filament\Pages\Tenancy\EditOrganizationProfile;


... panel provider boilerplate
->tenant(Organization::class)
->tenantProfile(EditOrganizationProfile::class);
```

I can navigate to the custom tenant profile page just fine:

[image]

However, when I click the "Save changes" button, I receive the following error:

```
Livewire
 \ 
Exceptions
 \ 
ComponentNotFoundException
PHP 8.2.10
10.17.1
Unable to find component: [app.filament.pages.tenancy.edit-organization-profile]
```

I have tried adding `mutateFormDataBeforeSave` and `handleRecordUpdate` overrides to make sure that it's not an error while saving my update.  Those overrides never get hit before the error occurs.  Any ideas?